# How Can I Use Multiple ItemTemplates inside of an ASP.NET ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, itemtemplate

So I have an ASP.NET ListView, which is bound to a collection of objects.  These objects have sub-collections, and I have an embedded ListView, which has an ItemTemplate for the sub-collections.  However, now the sub-collections contain items of multiple types, all inheriting from a base type.  How can I specify a different ItemTemplate for each of the different types of sub-objects?

Comment: The standard `ListView` control does not support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use other data controls like GridView and Repeater instead of ListView

Or

You have to code in this single ItemTemplate of ListView and you can also define collection and subcollection in it by separating via HTML(you can handle all the things via HTMl in a single ItemTemplate) somthing like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>//Your code</td>
     <td>//Bind the field using <%#Eval("FieldName")%></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>//Your code</td>
     <td>//Bind the field using <%#Eval("FieldName")%></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Hope it will help you.